# How to send response to API consumer after finishing working of async task created with celery?

Tags: django, websocket, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

I have a **REST API** (created using `django rest-framework`) exposed to USER_1. When USER_1 hits this API, my system creates a **async task** (created using `celery`). This task returns some result which I need to return back to USER_1. My question is, how to achieve this without blocking the thread? I tried using `.get()` method of tasks but it blocks the main thread which defeats the purpose of running tasks asynchronously.

Following is structure of my code:
**views.py**

```
class MyAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        task = some_async_task.delay()
        # Need a way here to get result returned by async task
        # for now sending some static response
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Success'})
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def some_async_task():
    # some processing that takes few mins
    result = {'key1': 'value1'} # data I wish to send to USER_1
    return result
```

I have searched this already and found that some people are suggesting to use `websockets`. Honestly, I have no knowledge of `websockets`. How does this really work? Will USER_1 have to send me request through websockets? Or is it something that I need to implement at just my side? Or do we both have to implement this?
Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which celery backend you are using ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. I'm using celery 4.2.1, Django 2.1 and Redis as broker and result backend.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: @CarlKroegerIhl I had to changes my process. Because requesting results back from a celery task makes it work like a synchronous task. As for the other work that I had to do only once the task is finished, I moved to another task and chained it with the current task (using [Chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains), [Chords](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords)).